# sort -R is not an option in my OS

Tags: sorting

I have a couple OS that do not have sort -R to generate a random list from a txt file I have. For example, I am trying to use the following command:

```
sort -R file | head -20000 > newfile
```

I looked up the man pages in these OS and sure enough, the -R option is not listed.

What is an alternative that can generate a random list from a file and print to a new file?

CentOS 5

Comment: sort is part of coreutils - can it be updated?

Comment: This is CentOS 5, I learned.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
shuf file | head -n 20000 > newfile
```

or:

```
cat file | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<STDIN>);'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, shuf is not an available command either. It is Linux 2.6.18-406.el5 x86_64 from uname -mrs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shuf` command, if it is installed.

`shuf` can either take a file as its input

```
shuf file | head -n 20000 > newfile
```

or read from stdin

```
cat file | shuf | head -n 20000 > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | awk 'BEGIN{srand();}{print rand()"\t"$0}' | sort -k1 -n | cut -f2 | head -20000 > newfile
```

This is working out for me.

```
cat ALLEMAILS.txt | awk 'BEGIN{srand();}{print rand()"\t"$0}' | sort -k1 -n | cut -f2 | head -20000 | tee 20000random.txt
```

This for seeing progress.